# problem on linear operators

Tags: functional-analysis

consider the sequence of continuous linear operators $T_n$:$l^2$ $\to$ $l^2$ defined by $$ T_n(x)=(0,0,.....,0,x_{n+1},x_{n+2},.....) $$

for every x=$(x_1,x_2,.....)$$\in$ $l^2$ and n$\in$ $\Bbb N$.then for every x$\neq0$ in $l^2$

(a)both $\left\lVert T_n\right\rVert $ and $\left\lVert T_n(x)\right\rVert $ converge to zero

(b)$\left\lVert T_n\right\rVert $ $\to$ 0 but not $\left\lVert T_n(x)\right\rVert $

(c)$\left\lVert T_n\right\rVert $ does not converges to zero but $\left\lVert T_n(x)\right\rVert $ $\to$ 0

(d) neither of the two converge to zero

i am really not able to put any sort of thoughts upon this question...can anyone help me out?

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2):

For $x$ to be in $l^2$ we must have $\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k^2 < \infty$.  Because of the convergence of the series, for each $x$ we have $\sum_{k=n}^\infty x_k^2 \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.  This implies that for each $x$ we have $||T_n(x)||\to 0$.

$||T||=\sup_x ||Tx||/||x||$. For each $n$ suppose $y_{n+1}=1$, $y_k=0$ for all other $k$.  Then $||T_n||=\sup_x ||Tx||/||x||\ge ||T_ny||/||y||=1$.

Comment: but tthe answer given is (d)...

Comment: I cannot see my mistake, if there is any, and apologize for not being able to understand why the answer is (d).  If a series of positive terms, $\sum a_i$, converges, that means its partial sums approach the limit sum $L$, so that for any $\epsilon>0$ we have $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i> L-\epsilon$ for sufficiently large $n$.  To me that implies that $\sum_{i=n+1}^\infty a_i$ exists and is $<\epsilon$ for sufficiently large $n$.  I did make one error; I wrote $\sum x_k^2$ presuming real scalars when I should have written $\sum |x_k|^2$ in case they were complex.

Comment: @ForgotALot, you are correct in your post. Each $T_n$ is a projection operator, and so $\|T_n\|=1$ for each $n$. $T_n$ converges to $0$ in the strong operator topology, so $T_n(x) \to 0$ for each $x$, as you have proven.